# Как передать в фрагмент значение из Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Есть класс MainActivity, в нем есть метод,

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item),
```

который отвечает за запуск активностей или фрагментов в зависимости от выбранного элемента в меню. Есть один фрагмент в который нужно передать значение 1 и 2.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    FragmentLearnWords fragLearn = new FragmentLearnWords();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    if (id == R.id.nav_learn_words) {
        bundle.putInt("key", 1);
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fLearnWords);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_repetition_words) {
        bundle.putInt("key", 2);
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fLearnWords);
    }         

    fragLearn.setArguments(bundle);

    ft.commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

В фрагменте код такой:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        int i = bundle.getInt("key", 0);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Тост не выводится.
B чем может быть ошибка?

Информацию брал из этого [топика](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment)

Answer (score 2):

Эту сроку `fragLearn.setArguments(bundle);` надо вызвать до того, как вы отобразите фрагмент, т.е. перед вызовом `ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fLearnWords);`

Так же заметил, что вы решили "обернуть" вставку фрагмента в транзакцию.
Можно сделать проще гораздо и будет выглядеть лучше.
Как то так

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentLearnWords fragLearn = new FragmentLearnWords();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    if (id == R.id.nav_learn_words) {
        bundle.putInt("key", 1);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_repetition_words) {
        bundle.putInt("key", 2);
    }

    fragLearn.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainFrame, fLearnWords)
            .commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Так же советую для лучше производительности, заранее инициализировать drawer, а не дергать каждый раз `findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);`, потому что `findViewById` тяжелая операция и ее лучше выполнять один раз.